# JavaScript Number & String declaration

Tags: javascript, string, numbers, concatenation

I try to understand that how can I get a true logic on the following JavaScript code:

```
var x = "10";
var y = "20";
var result = x + y;
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = result;
```

**link:https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_numbers_add_strings4**

The OUTPUT of the following code is = 1020 in "Addition" operation. In my mind I think it's correct because it's the concatenation of two number as a string.

```
var x = "100";
var y = "10";
var z = x / y;   
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = z;
```

**link: https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_numbers_string1**

But the OUTPUT of the following code is = 10 in "Division" operation & it's can't count this two Number as a String. It calculated the two number as  number.
****Please anybody help me to that I will be understand it clearly.****

Comment: `/` makes no sense on non-numbers, so it coerces non-numbers to numbers. `+`'s concatenation does make sense for strings, so `<string> + <string>` doesn't result in any coercion.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript does its best to give you a reasonable answer regardless of what type of data you give it. In your first example it sees you are applying the + operator to two strings. This is a valid thing for it to do (concatenation), so no coercion is performed - the two strings are concatenated.

In your second example it sees you are applying the / operator to two strings. This is not a valid thing to do, but applying that operator to numbers would be valid, and the strings you gave it can both be represented as numbers, so that is what it does. It converts them to numbers and then performs this division.

This auto coercion can be very convenient (you don’t have to worry nearly so much about types in JavaScript as in other languages). Sometimes it can also be a bit dangerous in that it can give you results you don’t expect, but once you get to understand how and when the coercion is applied, the danger diminishes some.

Answer (score 0):

In javascript, division operator implictly converts strings to numbers and perform division
But for addition javascript considers it as string and perform concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

In javascript "+" operator is treated as concatenation operator if any of the arguments is string and "/" division operator has only "division operation associated with it.

Answer (score 0):

```
var a  = "1022";            //variable a&b takes a string.
var b = "2";     
var c = a/b;                //a and b are converted to number type implicitly 
                            //because strings have no function with '/'.
document.write(c + "<br>"); //prints division between a and b (a/b).
c = toString();             //converts c to string explicitly.
document.write(c);          //shows an error as i said string cant be divided!.
```

Let me know if I helped!

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is a loosely-typed language. This means we can do math with strings, (e.g. `"100" / "10" === 10`) and JavaScript automatically realizes it should interpret those strings as numbers.

*But then why isn't `"10" + "20"` equal to 30?*

JavaScript (perhaps poorly) decide to use the same operator (`+`) for string concatenation as well as addition. This means they had to decide whether number-like strings should be interpreted as strings or as numbers in this case, and string concatenation won. In fact, even `"10" + 20` and `10 + "20"` and `10 + "2" + 0` will all yield `"1020"`. If there's a string *somewhere*, string concatenation wins.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to read this for you.

http://2ality.com/2013/04/quirk-implicit-conversion.html

Primative type Number: Operate other type, valueOf() -> toString() -> TypeError

Primative type String: Operate other type, toString() -> valueOf() -> TypeError